# React whole page scrollbar when component goes offpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an app like this:

[image]

as you can see the middle component continues down out of page and that's why I need a scrollbar to scroll down to it. but I can only make it work if I attach it directly on the middle component but I want a regular whole page scrollbar.

here is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import OysterView from './components/OysterView.js'
import './uikit/uikit.css';
import './App.css';
import logo from './uikit/assets/images/hrm-white.svg';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">      
      <div className="App-header">
        <header>
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="HRM"/>
        </header>
      </div>
      <div className="OysterView">
       <OysterView />
       </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have tried setting it on different places but it does not recognize that the component is out of bounds so cant scroll down the `<OysterView />` component is the component that is out of bound so I have tried in CSS

```
  .App {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fafafa;
 position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: -2
}
```

tried this as well:

```
html{
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

which doesn't add anything at all and that is probably because .App has no height but if I add height the rest of the content gets pushed down so it solves nothing. I have tried adding it to the index.css html as well and that gives me an scrollbar but it cant be scrolled down. so I am al out of ideas here. how should I attack this? z-index on .App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have to scroll the component itself, just make its container full-screen so that the scrollbar will be on the right side of the window.

```css
  .modal-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .5 );
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  .modal-content {
      background: red;
      margin: 20%;
      height: 2000px;
  }
```

```html
Page content
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-content">
    Modal content
  </div>
</div>
```